# Android why does setActionView hide menu item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar

I when i try to remove the actionview from my action bar by calling MenuCompat.setActionView(menuitem, null) i end up with an invisible and unclickable menu item. The menu item just disappears and it only shows up when i call setActionView passing in a layout. If i call invalidateOptionsMenu(), it shows up but produces some weird result, like not showing the progress bar when i need it.

Here is the function that does both removing and adding the actionView. Its a refresh action:

```
public void refresh(boolean refreshing, boolean fragment) {
    if(refreshing == refreshed) {
        return;
    }
    refreshed = refreshing;

    final MenuItem refreshItem = optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh);

    if (optionsMenu != null) {
        if (refreshItem != null) {
            if (refreshing) {
                MenuItemCompat.setActionView(refreshItem, R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
                MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(refreshItem);
                if(fragment)
                    ((PhotoGridPagerFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FOR_PHOTO_GRID_PAGER_FRAGMENT)).refresh();
            } else {
                MenuItemCompat.setActionView(refreshItem, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was there a particular reason you wanted to set/unset the action view on a single menu item rather than doing something like having two items and setting visibility to one or the other?

Comment: The menu item is also used as a refresh button. When its clicked it should show the loading progress bar. Don't know if i can still achieve this with what you said. ?

Answer (score 0):

MenuItemCompat.setActionView(refreshItem, R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);

I think you cannot just send a layout ID. You need to inflate it first and then pass it as a parameter:

```
View newView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);

MenuItemCompat.setActionView(refreshItem, newView);
```

But we do not have enough info to be sure:
where is optionsMenu defined?

Comment: In onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: My question is. Is optionsMenu a member Var of your Activity Class?

Comment: This thread is getting a bit old, I would like to give it a try, but as @ElAbogato said we need more info. Can you provide you menu xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to set an icon for the MenuItem.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/refreshMenuItem" android:title="@string/refresh"
    app:showAsAction="always" android:icon="@mipmap/refresh" />
```